# how to clear cookies and Claim after logout?

Tags: model-view-controller, asp.net-identity

I am using Asp.Net MVC5 and logIN by  Identity

After LogIN to the site using three different accounts, an error message appears:
403 Forbidden Error

Maybe The problem on:
The LogOff not clear cookies and Claim

How I can fixed it
The LogOffin Account controller

```
// POST: /Account/LogOff
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult LogOff()
{
    AuthenticationManager.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
    return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account");
}
```